# How to print this value using AJAX JQUERY on HTML

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

**HTML**

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
$("#but").click(function(){

    $.ajax({
        url: "action.php",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "text",
        success: On_success,
        error: On_error
    });

    function On_success(response){
        alert(response);
        //$("#show").html(response);
    }

    function On_error(data){
       console.log(data);
    }      
    });
    });

  </script>
 </head>
 <body>

 <form action="action.php" method="post">
 <input type="text" name="mine">
 <input type="submit" id="but">
 </form>
 <p id="show">HI</p>
 </body>
 </html>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php

$name = $_POST['mine'];

echo $name;

?>
```

There is a input box, a submit button and a para tag on HTML
When I input a value and click the button.....the value is passed to PHP file...where the value is echoed.

Now using AJAX I fetch the response..(which should be value from the input box)

but the response I receive is :

[image: Image of response]

and then it goes on PHP page and displayed the input box value.

How should I print the value using AJAX response in the para tag?

Thanks in advance
Please help

Comment: use innerHtml in javascript or html in jquery

Comment: why are you using input type submit and form action if you want to post using ajax ?

Comment: i have very less exp. with AJAX...can you help me out? @Poria .....I will input the value and onclick that value should be displayed on the same page as a response from PHP page on the para tag

Comment: first of all change input type submit to type button and see if page loading stops and form is submitting with ajax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several things

1. do not submit the form if you want to stay on the page
2. move the functions you want to call later to a scope where they are available or have them as anonymous functions: `success: function() {...}`
3. send the data from the form

Like this:

```
$(function(){
  $("form").on("submit",function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); // or make the button it type="button:
    var data = $(this).serialize();
    $.ajax({
      url: "action.php", // or $(this).attr("action"),
      type: "POST",
      data: data,
      success: On_success,
      error: On_error
    });
  });
});
function On_success(response){
    $("#show").html(response);
}

function On_error(data){
   console.log(data);
}
```

Comment: still getting the same response @mplungjan

Comment: Did you send the mine (I updated the script to have data serialised

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39099883/why-does-the-value-of-tag-remains-tag-always    help with this please @mplungjan

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your action.php page, it's not getting your POST data. You need to send it in the ajax.

```
 $("form").submit(function(e) {      // Change the event to form submit
   e.preventDefault();
   $.ajax({
      url: $(this).attr("action"),    // Use the specified form action
      type: "POST",
      data: $(this).serialize(),     // All form data is serialized and sent to the action page
      success: On_success,
      error: On_error
  });
});

function On_success(response){
   console.log(response);       // Debug your response. 
   $("#show").html(response);
}
```

This should work just fine now.

Comment: Its still going PHP page to display the value....i want that value to be printed on HTML page itself

Comment: It should work fine. Have you tried exactly like in the answer?